# How to implement Flavours (minimal, standard, complete) and Checkbox Options with NSIS?

Tags: installation, nsis

I am struggling with the `Section` configuration of [NSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System).

I want to implement installation options as shown in the following mockup:

[image: Install Flavour Screen]

The drop down list contains the following elements:

- Minimal (only MyApp Core Components is selected),
- Standard (MyApp Core Components, Feature A/B/C, and the Feature's Required Components are selected),
- Complete (everything is selected), and
- Custom (not selectable but shown when modifying the atomic options).

"MyApp Core Components" is the required component, and I already have that implemented as there is a required option for only one section.

However, how do I set-up the other section (Feature A/B/C, and sub-sections)? How to automatically deselect the sub-sections (there may more than one) when the parent section becomes deactivated?
How to indent a section in general (like in the screenshot)?
And how to implement the drop down list with the automatic selection (override), and on the other side, change the drop down to "Custom" when the user changes features manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a tree layout you need to use `SectionGroup`. Use `SectionIn` to tie a `Section` to a specific `InstType`:

```
Page Components
Page InstFiles

InstType "Full"
!define IT_FULL 1
InstType "Minimal"
!define IT_MINIMAL 2


Section "Required stuff"
    SectionIn RO
SectionEnd

SectionGroup /e "G1"
    Section "G1:A"
        SectionIn ${IT_FULL} ${IT_MINIMAL}
    SectionEnd
    Section "G1:B"
        SectionIn ${IT_FULL}
    SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

Section "a section"
    SectionIn ${IT_FULL} ${IT_MINIMAL}
SectionEnd

Section "another section"
    SectionIn ${IT_FULL}
SectionEnd
```